# Change page container position in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website with Bootstrap3. I would like to place the whole page container to the left side of the viewport. position="absolute" moves the container as wished, but the responsive behavior gets lost (main container isn't fluid any more).
How can I achieve that?
Thank you in advance, Ralf

Answer (score 0):

The .container gets positioned in the middle of the viewport with a set `width` and `margin: 0 auto;`. If you set `margin-left` to `0` it should work.